# Ссылка на переменную

Tags: переменные, java

Глупый вопрос, но все же.
есть такой код:

```
int i = 10;
String s = "privet " + i;
System.out.println(s); // привет 10
i = 20;
System.out.println(s)// опять "привет 10", хотя переменная i изменилась
```

Возможно ли как-нибудь обновить то, что находится в переменной s не присваивая заново ей значение?

Comment: Значения строк в Java неизменяемые.  

Переменная s это ссылка на некое строковое значение (оно не меняется), если нужно, чтобы s ссылалась на новое, то его нужно создать и присвоить s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass{
String str;
public MyClass(String str){
    this.str = str;
}
public void Show (int i ){
    System.out.println(str + " " + i);
}
```

}

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass my = new MyClass("Privet");
        my.Show(10); //privet 10
        my.Show(20); //privet 20
 }
```

}

Вот так еще можно...

Answer (score 1):

создать класс `S`, у которого будет аттрибут `i`. Менять этот аттрибут.

Comment: class lol
     {
      int i;

      String get_my_string()
      {
       return "zaika" + this.i;
      }
     }

     lol l = new lol();

     l.i = 10;
     System.out.println(l.get_my_string());

     l.i = 20;
     System.out.println(l.get_my_string());

Answer (score 0):

только не "заноГо", а "заноВо". Сорри за придирку)
Почитайте про модифицируемые/не модифицируемые типы.
Вообще в джава все объекты передаются по ссылке, кроме примитивных типов, они передаются по копированию.
Т.е. строчка:

```
String s = "privet " + i;
```

Сформирует новый объект строки, куда скопирует значение i
Возможно Вам нужно нечто такое:

```
class SomeClass {
  int i;
  public String toString() {
    return "someString" + i;
  }
}
```

Но лично мое мнение, подобные вещи (с указателями) любят делать в СИ, в "джава таких не любят"(c) =)

Comment: В Си такого тоже нет. Было нечто подобное в Алгол-60 с параметрами функций/процедур (передача параметров "по наименованию -- by name"). Возможно где-то есть и сейчас.

Comment: я имел ввиду, передача ссылки на аргумент, который модифицируется внутри функции, а используется, потом не ее, без явного возвращения из функции, криво как-то объяснил...ну лан, чет не в настроении, я сегодня)

Comment: Судя по вопросу о String, реально сейчас @kanarisisgod вряд ли понадобится объект класса C1, член которого ссылается на другой объект (класса C2) , а в результате вызова C1.toString() появляется текущее значение независимо модифицируемого члена из C2.

--

@alexlz, аналогия с параметрами по имени в алголе здесь тоже не совсем корректна, т.к. там такой параметр (с тем самым поведением) существовал только внутри вызванной процедуры, ТС же желает, чтобы сфрмировалась ссылка на строку, значение которой при каждом обращении являается функцией локальной переменной.

Comment: хм..."а автор хотел сказать, что занавески синие"(c) ИМХО:имелось ввиду, что тут вопрос именно о ссылках и обращения к ним.
Т.е. вопрос именно почему не изменилось зависимое значение, после того как изменился элемент. И вопрос вполне стандартный, потому-что везде пишут, что Java передает значение по ссылке, именно по этому я указал на изменяемые/неизменяемые типы, что примитивные типы передаются по копированию, а объекты по ссылке. Пример с объектом - это ответ именно на вопрос в лоб).Аналогия с Си было, ради того, что в Си часто функции модифицируют аргументы внутри себя. Как-то так =)